syntax error at or near "n" when uploading to a postgis db. how to escape correclty?
I am getting a lot of error messages when uploading data to a postgis / PostgreSQL server. The issue seem to be unescaped characters in jsonb objects. this is an exemplary log from the db:
2024-06-03T14:42:30.781942282Z 2024-06-03 14:42:30.781 UTC [916] ERROR: syntax error at or near "n" at character 2401
2024-06-03T14:42:30.781978542Z 2024-06-03 14:42:30.781 UTC [916] STATEMENT:
2024-06-03T14:42:30.781984462Z INSERT INTO cj_geometry (metadataID, location, groundgeometry, bbox, cityjsonfeature)
2024-06-03T14:42:30.781990002Z VALUES ('d5eaa521-686a-490c-80ea-385bd0978711',
2024-06-03T14:42:30.781994662Z ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[1090750.5758874745,7091366.735992711]}'),3857),
2024-06-03T14:42:30.781999762Z ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[1090756.6500556513,7091357.322415222],[1090753.2715091056,7091377.62971956],[1090744.4895144769,7091376.1446406925],[1090747.8925513108,7091355.848590724],[1090756.6500556513,7091357.322415222]]]]}'),3857),
2024-06-03T14:42:30.782004902Z ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[1090744.4895144773,7091355.848590724],[1090756.6500556516,7091355.848590724],[1090756.6500556516,7091377.62971956],[1090744.4895144773,7091377.62971956],[1090744.4895144773,7091355.848590724]]]}'),3857),
2024-06-03T14:42:30.782011112Z '{"type":"CityJSONFeature","CityObjects":{"DEHH_10ba522c-cf3e-4a31-9e13-2461cc07760b":{"type":"Building","attributes":{"creationDate":"2022-01-25T00:00:00Z","Gemeindeschluessel":"02200226","DatenquelleDachhoehe":"5000","DatenquelleLage":"1000","DatenquelleBodenhoehe":"1300","QualitaetDacherkennung":"98","Hauskoordinate":"552855,224 5937304,646","Dachhoehe":"4.50462926016637","Firsthoehe":"10.7808235498845","Traufhoehe":"6.27619428971818","tridicon_Dachform":"Satteldachhaus","Grundrissaktualitaet":"2021-12-07","Geometrietyp2DReferenz":"Polygon","measuredHeight":10.781,"function":"31001_1010","roofType":"3100","storeysAboveGround":2},"geometry":[{"type":"Solid","lod":"2","boundaries":[[[[0,1,2,3]],[[1,4,5,2]],[[4,6,7,5]],[[6,0,3,7]],[[4,1,8]],[[0,6,9]],[[1,0,9,8]],[[6,4,8,9]],[[3,2,5,7]]]],"semantics":{"surfaces":[{"type":"WallSurface"},{"type":"WallSurface"},{"type":"WallSurface"},{"type":"WallSurface"},{"type":"WallSurface"},{"type":"WallSurface"},{"type":"RoofSurface","Flaechenneigung":"53.585978459148","Flaechenrichtung":"349.789794011771","Flaechengroesse":"40.166004137133"},{"type":"RoofSurface","Flaechenneigung":"53.5853859152926","Flaechenrichtung":"169.812724206374","Flaechengroesse":"40.1052971618594"},{"type":"GroundSurface"}],"values":[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]}}],"address":[{"Country":"Germany","Locality":"Hamburg","ThoroughfareNumber":"105","ThoroughfareNumberSuffix":"e","ThoroughfareName":"Op'n Hainholt","PostCode":"22589"}]}},"vertices":[[1423187,532395,12580],[1431969,533881,12580],[1431969,533881,6304],[1423187,532395,6304],[1435347,513573,12580],[1435347,513573,6304],[1426590,512099,12580],[1426590,512099,6304],[1433658,523727,17085],[1424889,522248,17085]],"id":"DEHH_10ba522c-cf3e-4a31-9e13-2461cc07760b"}')
2024-06-03T14:42:30.782048142Z

I am uploading from a typescript / nodejs program like this:
          const cityjsonfeature = cityjsonFeature
          const location = point([centerCoordinates[0], centerCoordinates[1]]).geometry

          //push!
          const insertGeometryQuery = `
                              INSERT INTO cj_geometry (metadataID, location, groundgeometry, bbox, cityjsonfeature)
                              VALUES ('${metaDataID}',
                              ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('${JSON.stringify(location)}'),3857),
                              ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('${JSON.stringify(
                                groundGeometry.features[0].geometry
                              )}'),3857),
                              ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('${JSON.stringify(
                                boundingbox.geometry
                              )}'),3857),
                                '${JSON.stringify(cityjsonfeature)}')
                                `

          try {
            await lodsql.unsafe(insertGeometryQuery).execute()
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.stack)
          }

I think I should somehow escape characters which to into the                                 '${JSON.stringify(cityjsonfeature)}') line. but how would I do that? is there a general way to get rid of non working characters? or do I have to set up the query string differently?
in the provided log it seems that the problem is: "ThoroughfareName": "Op'n Hainholt", and more precisely the "'" in "Op'n".
any idea how to get rid of this problem would be awesome!
Thanks a lot!

Looks like you have an issue with SQL injection, I don't see any placeholders in your SQL statement. https://node-postgres.com And when this issue is solved, fix the rest of your code as well. It's not safe.

Hi, can you elaborate on this a little bit more? Where should i look for what? And why is there an issue with sql injection?

There is a quote in your content and your SQL breaks. That can only happen because of SQL injection, otherwise the database would have escaped this quote. Use prepared statements to work safely with databases, and nothing else. Or stop using databases, that's also an option.

ok, i did some reading. Thanks a lot for that hint! In my case here i am filling a database one time. i think i will lock the database after upload then like this: ALTER DATABASE (database) SET default_transaction_read_only = true; that should make it safe(er) doesn't it?

No it doesn't, your application code is wrong. That's where you open the doors for SQL injection. Your application must use prepared statements. You must use place holders like $1, $2, etc. in your SQL statement and let the database replace the place holders with the content that it receives separately. Check these examples: https://node-postgres.com/features/queries
